# 'No entry is registered for key 'Zend_Translate'

Tags: php, zend-framework

So I have to change a website which was written on Zend framework. I downloaded the source files and want to run the website locally. But I keep getting this error 'No entry is registered for key 'Zend_Translate'. I have no experience with the Zend framework, so I dont really know what is the problem now. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application requires Translator and it needs to be linked in Registry. Basically you need to add Transaltor (if it's not added already):

```
//Bootstrap.php
$locale = new Zend_Locale('en_GB'); //current locale
Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Locale', $locale); //this is optional but better to add this
$translate = new Zend_Translate(array('adapter' => 'tmx',
    'content' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/translations.tmx',
    'locale' => $locale));
Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Translate', $translator); //here you add translator to registry
```

In this case translation file is `translations.tmx` which has syntax like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tmx SYSTEM "tmx14.dtd">
<tmx version="1.4">
   <body>
       <tu tuid='ADD_BASKET'>
            <tuv xml:lang="pl_PL"><seg>Dodaj do koszyka</seg></tuv>
            <tuv xml:lang="en_GB">Add to basket<seg></seg></tuv>
       </tu>
       <tu tuid='RECRIUT'>
            <tuv xml:lang="pl_PL"><seg>rekrutacja</seg></tuv>
            <tuv xml:lang="en_GB"><seg>recruit</seg></tuv>
       </tu>
   </body>
</tmx>
```

Zend supports interfaces to few other translation file formats if you need.